# jquery .prev() strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

I have a very simple list of LI's and they are all on the same level (nothing nested) I want to find the previous element of any element who's class is level1. For some reason prev() is failing on items when the 'level1' element is more than one sibling away. I don't want to use prevAll() because I only want the closest li that comes before my element and has a class of level1.

```
<ul id="main-list">
    <li class="level1" data-id="1" data-parent="none" id="recordsArray_1">Overview</li>
    <li class="level2" data-id="4" data-parent="Overview" id="recordsArray_4">Benefits</li>
    <li class="level2" data-id="2" data-parent="undefined" id="recordsArray_2">Core Concepts</li>
    <li class="level2" data-id="3" data-parent="undefined" id="recordsArray_3">Access</li>
    <li class="level3" data-id="5" data-parent="Access" id="recordsArray_5">Onboarding</li>
    <li class="level1" data-id="12" data-parent="none" id="recordsArray_12">test top</li>
    <li class="level2" data-id="10" data-parent="test top" id="recordsArray_10">test 1</li>
    <li class="level2" data-id="14" data-parent="undefined" id="recordsArray_14">New Access</li>
    <li class="level3" data-id="13" data-parent="New Access" id="recordsArray_13">test 2</li>
    <li class="level1" data-id="6" data-parent="none" id="recordsArray_6">Underview</li>
    <li class="level2" data-id="7" data-parent="Underview" id="recordsArray_7">coolpage1</li>
    <li class="level3" data-id="9" data-parent="coolpage1" id="recordsArray_9">page level 3</li>
</ul>

<script>
var publishList = $('#main-list li');

$.each(publishList, function () {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var parentID = $(this).attr('data-parent');
    var recordID = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if (thisClass == 'level2') {
        var thisParent = $(this).prev('.level1').html();
        console.log(this);    
    }
}); 
</script>
```

console output:

```
Overview
undefined
undefined
test top
undefined
Underview
```

What am I doing wrong? I expected prev() to return overview for core concepts, access and New Access but they are coming back undefined. Is there a flaw in my logic?

Comment: `.prev()` get's exactly that, the previous sibling filtered by a selector. If the previous sibling isn't a match it doesn't go any further. "Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector."

Comment: Prev only ever returns the object immediately before the selector in the DOM. Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: Added a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/y3ywr/3/

Comment: Ahh I see. I read the documentation several times but I did not realize it only goes up the tree one spot. Well that says what I am doing wrong. But how do I do it right?

Comment: There's prevUntil(), perhaps that's better suited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a combination of `.prevAll()` and `.first()`

```
var thisParent = $(this).prevAll('.level1').first().html();
```

This will make sure you always get the closest possible sibling no matter the distance.

Try this code

```
var publishList = $('#main-list li');

$.each(publishList, function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        thisClass = $this.attr('class'),
        parentID = $this.attr('data-parent'),
        recordID = $this.attr('data-id');

    if (thisClass == 'level2') {
        var thisParent = $this.prevAll('.level1').first().html();
        $('#output').append($this.prevAll('.level1').first().html()+'<br />');
    }

});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3ywr/4/)**

Comment: Nailed it. This is exactly the functionality I was looking for. Thanks sushanth. Once I realized prev() only went one spot up on the tree first() came to mind, tested this and it worked.

Comment: @RAC. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

`.prev()` doesn't provide the functionality you want. The functionality you're looking for is in [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

Once you have a set of values from `.prevAll()` you can use something like `.first()` to get what you need (as has been mentioned) or identify the closest element by id (i.e. `.split()` a number-based id or some similar method). However you decide to go about it, `.prev()` won't get you what you want.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: No, not really. The OP already mentioned not wanting to use .prevAll() as a possible solution so he's obviously aware of it. Your answer should provide an actual solution, not just a hint or suggestion. That's what comments are for.

Comment: @Sushanth beat me to it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Thanks for the input!

Comment: @j08691 even an altogether wrong answer is not "not an answer" :)

Answer (score 0):

Just update your if statement with that

```
    if (thisClass == 'level2' && $(this).prev('.level1').length) {
```